# pytest runs almost 10 times longer with python3.7 compared to python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, tox

I'm running pytests on a module called pdf2textbox, and to do that I use tox.       Setup for python 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7 is identical:

```
# tox.ini  
...   
[testenv]
    basepyton =  
        py35: python3.5  
        py36: python3.6  
        py37: python3.7  

    deps =
        check-manifest  
        pytest  
        requests  
        pdfminer2  
        pytest-cov  

    commands =
        check-manifest  
        python --version  
        py.test --cov=pdf2textbox tests
```

When I'm running tox, the time for python3.5 and python3.6 is around 58 or 59 seconds. However, python3.7 takes about 8 minutes:

```
py36 inst-nodeps: .../.virtualenvs/pdf2textbox/.tox/dist/pdf2textbox-0.2.6.zip  
py36 installed: atomicwrites==1.1.5,attrs==18.1.0,certifi==2018.4.16,chardet==3.0.4,check-manifest==0.37,coverage==4.5.1,idna==2.7,more-itertools==4.2.0, pdf2textbox==0.2.6, pdfminer2==20151206,pluggy==0.6.0,py==1.5.4,pytest==3.6.3,pytest-cov==2.5.1, requests==2.19.1, six==1.11.0,urllib3==1.23  
py36 runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='1111111111'  
py36 runtests: commands[0] | check-manifest  
some files listed as being under source control are missing:  
.tox/dist/pdf2textbox-0.2.4.zip  
lists of files in version control and sdist match  

py36 runtests: commands[1] | python --version  
Python 3.6.3

py36 runtests: commands[2] | py.test --cov=pdf2textbox tests  
============================ test session starts =============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.6.3, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.6.0  
rootdir: .../.virtualenvs/pdf2textbox, inifile:  
plugins: cov-2.5.1
collected 15 items                                                                    

tests/test_cli_slice_option.py ...         [ 20%]  
tests/test_convert_pdf.py ........         [ 60%]  
tests/test_get_pdf.py ............         [ 86%]  
tests/test_types.py ..............         [100%]

----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.6.3-final-0 -----------  
Name                                       Stmts     Miss       Cover  
pdf2textbox/__init__.py                        1        0        100%  
pdf2textbox/pdf2textbox.py                   507      201         60%

TOTAL                                        508      201         60%

**================== 15 passed in 58.93 seconds ==============================**
py37 inst-nodeps: .../.virtualenvs/pdf2textbox/.tox/dist/pdf2textbox-0.2.6.zip  
py37 installed: atomicwrites==1.1.5,attrs==18.1.0,certifi==2018.4.16,chardet==3.0.4,check-manifest==0.37,coverage==4.5.1,idna==2.7,more-itertools==4.2.0,pdf2textbox==0.2.6,pdfminer2==20151206,pluggy==0.6.0,py==1.5.4,pytest==3.6.3,pytest-cov==2.5.1,requests==2.19.1,six==1.11.0,urllib3==1.23   
py37 runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='2222222222'   
py37 runtests: commands[0] | check-manifest   
some files listed as being under source control are missing:   
.tox/dist/pdf2textbox-0.2.4.zip   
lists of files in version control and sdist match   

py37 runtests: commands[1] | python --version   
Python 3.7.0b3   

py37 runtests: commands[2] | py.test --cov=pdf2textbox tests   
========================== test session starts =================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.0b3, pytest-3.6.3, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.6.0   
rootdir: .../.virtualenvs/pdf2textbox, inifile:   
plugins: cov-2.5.1 collected 15 items                                                                    

tests/test_cli_slice_option.py ...         [ 20%]  
tests/test_convert_pdf.py ........         [ 60%]  
tests/test_get_pdf.py ............         [ 86%]  
tests/test_types.py ..............         [100%]

----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.7.0-beta-3 -----------  
Name                                       Stmts     Miss       Cover  
pdf2textbox/__init__.py                        1        0        100%  
pdf2textbox/pdf2textbox.py                   507      201         60%

TOTAL                                        508      201         60%


**=================== 15 passed in 461.68 seconds =============================**

_______________________________ summary _______________________________________
  py35: commands succeeded   
  py36: commands succeeded   
  py37: commands succeeded   
  congratulations :)
```

Testing times:
py35: 1 minute
py36: 1 minute
py37: 8 minutes

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Can you rerun the tests with `pytest --durations=0`? It will show you run times per test, maybe you can cut the problem down to a single test. Also, why `Python 3.7b3`? Can you test whether the issue persist with the release version?

Comment: @hoefling: ran the tests again:

419.79s call     tests/test_cli_slice_option.py::test_pdf_to_text_slice     
9.30s call     tests/test_types.py::test_textbox_structure  
9.26s call     tests/test_types.py::test_pdf_to_text_all  
3.41s call     tests/test_convert_pdf.py::test_convert_three_cols_and_header  
3.39s call     tests/test_convert_pdf.py::test_convert_three_cols  
3.09s call     tests/test_convert_pdf.py::test_convert_two_cols  
3.08s call     tests/test_convert_pdf.py::test_convert_two_cols_and_header

Comment: @hoefling: After installing Python 3.7.0 the times stayed the same, i.e. no improvement :(

Comment: Hmm, another guess would be a coverage regression? Can you temporarily turn off coverage and check whether the running time improves?

Comment: Yes, running the tests without coverage does the trick. It's reducing the times to 38 (py35), 39 (py36) and 35 seconds (py37).

Comment: Well, `coverage` support for Python 3.7 is still young, so if the `coverage` version used on Travis is the latest one (4.5.1 atm), you could [open a new issue in coverage project repo](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues).

Comment: OK, [here](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/679) is the new issue.

Comment: @hoefling: Issue has been resolved by using `(vEnv)$ tox --recreate`